# Cannot import name 'BlobClient' from 'azure.storage.blob. Django

Tags: django, azure, django-rest-framework

Although, there are many similar questions to the one I am asking, but non of them have helped me.

I am trying to store the file into my azure storage blob through directly through my system using Django. can some help me?

Here is the result of pip freeze:

```
azure-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-servicebus==0.21.1
azure-servicefabric==6.3.0.0
azure-servicemanagement-legacy==0.20.7
azure-storage-blob==1.5.0
azure-storage-common==1.4.2
azure-storage-file==1.4.0
azure-storage-queue==1.4.0
```

I got the following importerror:

```
    from azure.storage.blob import (
    ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobClient' from 'azure.storage.blob'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reinstalling `azure-storage-blob`.

Unistall: `python3 -m pip uninstall azure-storage-blob`

Install: `python3 -m pip install azure-storage-blob`

You can refer to similar bugs: [cannot import name 'BlobClient' from 'azure.storage.blob](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/3645#issuecomment-861380402) and [ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobServiceClient' from 'azure.storage.blob'](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/10099#issuecomment-624035807)